# RecyclerView onClick() not working, instead of it only responding to when I click a single element

Tags: android, onclick, android-recyclerview

My title could not be very descriptive because of a character limit. My goal is that when I click an element INSIDE the `recyclerView` it prints out the `RecyclerView` position(basically index).

Using `OnClick()` with XML and regular `OnClick` methods just crash my app.

```
public class torrentAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<torrentAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private List<torrent> seznamTorrentov;

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView upSpeed, downSpeed, progress, name;
        public ImageView delete, stanje;

        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
            upSpeed = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.upSpeed);
            downSpeed = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.downSpeed);
            progress = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.progress);
            delete = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.zbrisi);
            stanje = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.stanje);
        }
    }


    public torrentAdapter(List<torrent> seznamTorrentov) {
        this.seznamTorrentov = seznamTorrentov;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.torrenti_vrsta, parent, false);

        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);

    }

    @Override

    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        torrent torrent = seznamTorrentov.get(position);
        holder.name.setText(torrent.getName());
        holder.delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                System.out.println("POZICIJA " + position);
            }
        });
        holder.progress.setText(String.valueOf(torrent.getProgress() + "%"));
        //TUKAJ ZAOKROŽUJEMO VREDNOSTI
        //TRENUTNO NI PODPORE ZA GIGABITNE PRENOSE
        //S SPREMENLJIVKAMA sizeUname in Dname spreminjamo, ali napišemo na koncu hitrosti downloada MB/S ali KB/s
        int sizeD = 1024;
        int sizeU = 1024;
        String sizeUname = "KB/s";
        String sizeDname = "KB/s";
        if (torrent.getDownSpeed() > 1000000) {
            sizeD = 1024 * 1024;
            sizeDname = "MB/s";
        }
        if (torrent.getUpSpeed() > 1000000) {
            sizeU = 1024 * 1024;
            sizeUname = "MB/s";
        }

        holder.downSpeed.setText(String.valueOf(Math.round(torrent.getDownSpeed()) / sizeD) + sizeDname);
        holder.upSpeed.setText(String.valueOf(Math.round(torrent.getUpSpeed()) / sizeU) + sizeUname);
        //TODO: ZRIHTAJ,DA SE POJAVIJO SLIKE IN PROGRESS BAR
        if (torrent.getDownSpeed() == 0 && torrent.getUpSpeed() == 0) {
            holder.stanje.setImageResource(R.drawable.check);

        }
        if (torrent.getStanje().contains("Stopped") || torrent.getStanje().contains("Paused")) {
            holder.stanje.setImageResource((R.drawable.stop));
        }
        if (torrent.getStanje().contains("Downloading")) {
            holder.stanje.setImageResource(R.drawable.down);


        }
        if (torrent.getStanje().contains("Seeding")) {
            holder.stanje.setImageResource(R.drawable.up);
        }

        holder.delete.setImageResource(R.drawable.delete);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return seznamTorrentov.size();
    }
}
```

This is my `RecyclerViewAdapter`. Delete is the `drawable` I would like to `OnClick` listen. With my current implementation I get responses no matter where I click on the `RecyclerView`. This is an issue because I am supposed to have two different "buttons" that have their own functions when clicked.

If it's relevant, this is the error I get when I use `OnClick` with XML:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method deleteTorrent(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView with id 'zbrisi'

Comment: Can you add more detail that what exactly do you want?,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have mentioned an property in your adapter layout xml tag with this id
 zbrisi like this

```
android:onclick="deleteTorrent"
```

remove this as it will interfere with you current `onClickListener` method

Comment: I did delete it in the XML. Is the code correct otherwise?

Comment: Wow. Can't believe this happened. I didnt delete the onClick in XML even though I checked three times. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

if `onclick` is defined in the xml then it has to be implemented in the java

ie.

```
android:onclick="delete"
```

java must have

```
public void delete(){//codes here}
```

but i recommend not doing this as there is a better way which is to implement `onClickListener` on the view itself

Comment: I've done that as soon as I wanted to implement the onClick in the code, without using. I just added the error just in case it helped with my problem.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood you correctly, code above returns you wrong position? What is the position? 0? 1? Or each time that's different? Try to change "public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, final int position)" to "public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position)".

Comment: No it returns the correct position. But the problem is that it returns the correct position no matter where on a single RecyclerView I click.